# How can I keep and remember all the characters in the dialogue/s and how can I insert a new one in the middle of the array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 scripts:

The first one is the manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Text nameText;
    public float sentencesSwitchDuration;
    public bool animateSentenceChars = false;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public static bool dialogueEnded = false;
    public DialogueTrigger trigger;

    private Queue<string> sentence;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        sentence = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        canvas.SetActive(true);

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;

        sentence.Clear();
        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
            this.sentence.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if (this.sentence.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = this.sentence.Dequeue();
        dialogueText.text = sentence;

        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(sentence));
    }

    public IEnumerator DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(string sentence)
    {
        if (animateSentenceChars)
        {
            dialogueText.text = "";
            foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
            {
                dialogueText.text += letter;
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sentencesSwitchDuration);
        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    private void EndDialogue()
    {
        dialogueEnded = true;
        if (trigger.dialogueNum == trigger.dialogue.Length)
            canvas.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("End of conversation.");
    }
}
```

The second one is the trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue[] dialogue;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueNum = 0;

    private bool triggered = false;
    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        if (triggered == false)
        {
            if (FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>() != null)
            {
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue[dialogueNum]);
                dialogueNum += 1;
            }
            triggered = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == true)
        {
            if (dialogueNum == dialogue.Length)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue[dialogueNum]);
                DialogueManager.dialogueEnded = false;
                dialogueNum += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last one is the dialogue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public string name;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string[] sentences;
}
```

For example in the trigger script the array dialogue contains 3 dialogues.
The first one name is: Jhon the second Player the third Npc

The first one have 2 sentences the second have 5 sentences the last one have 1 sentence.

The problem is if in the editor I set the array of dialogues to 1 it will delete the other two. And if I will change it back to 3 it will add twice the same of the first one and will not remember the two others.

What I want to do is to add to the trigger script a global bool flag:

If true remember all the characters names and sentences if changing the dialogue array. If changing the array size higher or lower to 1 or 0 remember the characters and sentences of them.

If false don't remember the characters names and sentences if changed the dialogue array to 0 but if changed the dialogue array to 1 then remember the first one and don't remember the other two. And then if I change the dialogue array size to 3 again since the flag is false remember the first one and create two new empty dialogues.

The second problem I have is each time when I change the dialogue array size for example the size was 3 and I changed it now to 4 there is a new place in the end at the bottom. But is there a way to be able to decide to insert a new name to the chat for example in the middle of the array ? For example at the second place or third place and not always in the end ? In the editor in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is to use a List instead of an array. A list will allow you to insert a new record wherever you want and also have varying lengths with no problems.